# Python SQL Query gives back wrong results

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I want to create 2 Views and safe them in Oracle. So far so good, the values in the views work fine and are correct. The Problem is, when I afterwards want to adress these values, I get randomly wrong values.

So I get all the values, from the ID and the lower and the upper boarders (not important for that case I guess, because the values are correct), but around 40% auf my lower and upper values, so the 2 values from the Select query, are just wrong. Is it possible, that Python can not handle so many SQL-Commands in a short time?

Code:

```
dsn= cx_Oracle.makedsn("*****.******",1521,"orcl")
db= cx_Oracle.connect('******','******',dsn)
db.autocommit = True
_tabelle ='******'
cur = db.cursor()


 cur.execute("CREATE VIEW convert_cat_%s (quotient, %s, rnum) AS SELECT (COUNT(*)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %s ) ) as quotient, %s, row_number() over ( order by (COUNT(*)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %s ) ) desc ) as rnum FROM     %s  GROUP BY %s ORDER BY quotient desc" %convert_cat)
    cur.execute("CREATE VIEW boarders_%s AS Select b.ID,a.unten as lower ,a.oben as upper FROM( SELECT t3.RNUM, t3.%s, lag(t3.com_Pr,1,0) OVER (order by rnum asc) as unten , t3.com_PR as oben FROM( SELECT t1.rnum, t1.%s , SUM(t2.quotient) as com_Pr FROM CONVERT_CAT_%s t1 INNER JOIN CONVERT_CAT_%s t2 ON t1.rnum >= t2.rnum group by t1.rnum, t1.%s, t1.quotient ORDER BY RNUM asc ) t3) a INNER JOIN %s b ON b.%s = a.%s order by ID asc" %calculate)
    get_id=(name_convert_column)
    #That Query gives back wrong values, even if the view itself, created in 
    #the row before is correct
    cur.execute("Select id, lower, upper FROM boarders_%s ORDER BY id asc" % get_id)

    lower = {}
    upper ={}
    for row in cur:
        lower.update({row[0]: float(row[1])})
        upper.update({row[0]: float(row[2])})
        print row[0], row[1],row[2]
    for key in lower:
        key =key
        lower_boarder = lower.get(key)
        upper_boarder = upper.get(key)
        print key, lower_boarder,upper_boarder
```

Its not the full code, but the rest are not important I guess :)
If you can help me in any way, why sometimes there are just random wrong values, I would appreciate. If I run that script multiple times, after a while, the results are correct :/

EDIT:

The whole codes iterates through a table and do the shown code for multiple categorical columns. For 4/5 Columns it works perfectly. The row which has the wrong values, is a value with very small boarders. The views calculate the cumulative probability and seperates a range from [0;1] in multiple ranges. F.e. (an easy example):
I have 100 people, 70 men, 30 women
[0;0.3] - Women
[0.3;1] - Men

The Column with the mistake has a lot of categories, therefore the ranges are very small and the boarders are quite close to each other (3-4 digits after the comma)....

maybe that information helps?

Comment: Is `boarders_%s` an actual table name?  AFAIK it is not possible to parameterize table or column names in a prepared statement.

Comment: No, its a view. But its working, the View boarders_%s  (where %s is the variable name) exists and is correct

Comment: why you need create these two view before make select? why just you do not make one select statment, it will be much clear what are you doing in exec.

Comment: I tried before, but then I found out that I get wrong values. So I created a view, to be sure that the query itself is correct and to compare the results...The view is more or less a "help view" to detect which values are wrong.

Comment: By the way, I tried the statement without Creating multiple Views, it still has the same problems. I have everything in 1 large Query, doesnt help...